# How to search for # or . in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field, under a type company, in my elasticsearch index which captures the technologies that the company uses. So people coming to our site might enter `java`, `Java`, `C#`, `c#`, `.Net`, `.net`etc in the search box to get the companies.

Initially I indexed this in the default way and then I couldn't search for `.Net` or `C#` as there were wildcard characters in the search query. When I searched with `Net` or `C` it returned companies that uses `C` or `C#` , which again is not correct.

I did some research and changed the mapping for the field to `"index": "not_analyzed"` and re-indexed the companies. Now it returned the correct companies for `C#` and `.Net`, but failed in the case were the search term was not an exact match. So it didn't return companies with `Java` technologies, when the search term was `java`, but it returned correctly when the search term was `java`. I understand that `not_analyzed` requires exact match

How do I index and query on the same field to get both these cases sorted out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve what you need is to create a custom analyzer that does a little bit more than what `not_analyzed` does, i.e. also lowercase the terms.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then when you index a document that contains `Java`, it will be indexed as `java`, `C#` as `c#`, etc

This will bring the benefits of case-insensitive exact matches.